# \ character in cn after user insertion through powershell script

Tags: powershell

```
New-adviser -name “smith, Corbin” -accountpassword (read-host -assecurestring) -enabled $true -givenname $firstname -surname $lastname -path $oupath -samaccountname $username
```

Result:

```
cn=Corbin\, smith,ou=one,ou=temp,dc=test,dc=com
```

Instead of:

```
cn=Corbin, smith,ou=one,ou=temp,dc=test,dc=com
```

Tried adding the trim() function to the end but still the same result

Comment: The ``\`` is expected and necessary: Since `,` is the character that separates the `<key>=<value>` pair components in a distinguished name, any value that itself contains `,` characters must have them _escaped_, namely as ``\,``

Comment: and please also fix the smart quotes like in `“smith, Corbin”`. They're invalid in almost all programming languages. Use straight quotes only `""`

Comment: Hi @mklement0, thanks for the clarification. In turn, does the escaped character appear in the CN post-creation of the new user?

Comment: Yes - that is a syntactic necessity.